# Using LZ4 to Add to an existing .lz4 (zip) in Java

Tags: java, lz4

I am compressing in java using the following and the LZ4 library. If I try to call this method again on the same file name, it overwrites with the new contents instead of appending. Is there a way to append using LZ4? I just want to add another file to the existing zip archive at a later time.

```
public void zipFile(File[] fileToZip, String outputFileName, boolean activeZip)
{
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName));
            LZ4FrameOutputStream lz4fos = new LZ4FrameOutputStream(fos);)
    {
        for (File a : fileToZip)
        {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(a))
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSizeZip];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buf)) > 0)
                {
                    lz4fos.write(buf, 0, length);
                }
            }                
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOG.error("Zipping file failed ", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could figure out how to do this is to send

```
new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName),false)
```

in the try-with-resources